# MySQL Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint for geometry datatype POINT

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to create a foreign key constraint with column `latlong`, as show in the picture, but I am receiving an error code (1215) with my given code.
If I change the data type of `latlong` to int, the code functions properly, giving me the idea that the cause of this issue is the POINT data type in creation of foreign key constraints. 
Given that POINT is a zero-dimensional geometry object, it cannot be instantiated with a default value, so I know this is not an issue either.

There must be some special attribute of the POINT datatype I am unaware of, but the available resources online have not helped me to solve this issue.

Current code is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `notablesurroundingareas` (  
  `nsa_id` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,  
  `latlong` POINT NOT NULL,  
  `nsa_location_type` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',  
  `nsa_location_name` varchar(30) DEFAULT '',  
  PRIMARY KEY (`nsa_id`),  
  KEY (`latlong`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `locationinformation` (  
  `latlong` POINT NOT NULL,  
  `li_city` varchar(30) DEFAULT '',  
  `li_zip_code` int(5) DEFAULT 0,  
  `li_area_code` int(3) DEFAULT 0,  
  FOREIGN KEY (`latlong`)   
  REFERENCES notablesurroundingareas(`latlong`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

As said above, when I change the data type of my POINT foreign key `latlong` to `int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0` the code runs as intended.

Comment: Please provide us with code samples of what you tried until now. That way we can help you more effectively. Pictures make it difficult to cut and paste

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the document to include the code

Answer (score 0):

Intruiging:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

> Index prefixes on foreign key columns are not supported. One consequence of this is that BLOB and TEXT columns cannot be included in a foreign key because indexes on those columns must always include a prefix length.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/gis-data-formats.html (regarding `POINT`)

> Well-Known Binary (WKB) Format
>   The Well-Known Binary (WKB) representation of geometric values is used for exchanging geometry data as binary streams represented by BLOB values

or

> Well-Known Text (WKT) Format
>   The Well-Known Text (WKT) representation of geometry values is designed for exchanging geometry data in ASCII form.

Seems thats the reason you can not use it as FK. They are either represented as Text or Blob and neither is allowed.